# OmniAuth/OAuth Authentication from a ruby script

Tags: ruby, oauth, omniauth

Is there a way I can test out the OmniAuth authentication from a standalone ruby script?
Every resource I could find on web lists its usage only in Rails project.This link too: http://www.omniauth.org/

In other words I could not find any client like this [FitGem](https://github.com/whazzmaster/fitgem/wiki/The-OAuth-Process). The fitbit [API](https://wiki.fitbit.com/display/API/OAuth+Authentication+in+the+Fitbit+API) uses Oauth authentication.FitGem is a client inteface to test out the authentication/authorization to FitBit using OAuth token.
More details here on FitGem: http://www.fitbitclient.com/guide/getting-started

Thanks.

Comment: omniauth it meant to work with rack based frameworks. That includes rails and a bunch of others. There are sinatra examples in the documentation for example.

Comment: I guess usage examples documented [here](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2#usage-examples) can be useful for the desired purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is old, but I came across it whilst googling so others might also. Maybe this will help the next passerby...

To answer the question - no, it isn't possible to use OmniAuth within a simple, standalone script. What froderik said is correct, OmniAuth was designed to be used within an app on a rack-based framework (Rails, Sinatra, Pakyow, etc.).

To expand on that just a bit though, OmniAuth relies on the ability to intercept and send HTTP requests to/from your app. By default, OmniAuth intercepts requests to `/auth/:provider` to kickoff the authorization process and will then send callbacks to either `/auth/:provider/callback` or `/auth/failure` depending on the outcome of the auth attempt.

Obviously, that functionality is beyond the scope of a standalone script. But if I were to recommend a solution for writing a quick test using OmniAuth, I'd recommend [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/). It's certainly not the only solution (any rack-based framework will do), but it provides the needed functionality with minimal overhead.